# Is it possible to have two switches controlling the same motor?

Tags: motor, switches

Basically I want one (3 prong)switch to allow the motor to spin in one direction, and the second (3 prong)switch will allow it to spin in the opposite direction. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: And if you use both switches, what then?

Comment: Nothing, thats what i would hope but that shouldn't happen

Comment: @Majenko I think Zivicium implies a bipolar switch with central OFF position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you could get is to use the switches as a H bridge. Certain combinations of switch positions would then give different motor operations:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f278Aj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With both switches in the same position the motor will be stopped. With the switches in alternating positions the motor will spin, the direction dependent on which switch is "up" and which switch is "down".

Answer (score 0):

You could have a DPDT relay acting as a motor reversing switch: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [quadomated.com](http://www.quadomated.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Multi-Direction-DC-Motor-Control-with-Two-Relays.jpg))</sub>

The above picture should give the general idea - just imagine that both SPDT relays are one combined relay.

Next you can wire two switches together so that either switch will reverse the direction of the motor by activating/deactivating the relay coil: -

[image]

OK, the lamp is the relay coil in this example. If the relay coil is DC then replace the AC supply with the appropriate DC supply for the relay coil.

Alternatively you could use a H bridge and activate the direction using the same switch arrangement shown in the 2nd diagram.

Comment: It's called a [H bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge).

Comment: @tigrou read my last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just a switch, you can use a double-pole, double-throw (DPDT) switch. DPDT switches are available with and without a "center off" position. As you can see from other answers, it is not very convenient to use two switches.

[image]

Here is a way to do it with momentary-contact pushbuttons and relays.

[image]